# Use regex to add string to different multilines with simularities

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a .txt file with multiple lines (Different yet simular for each one) that I want to add a "*.tmp" at the end.

I'm trying to use python2.7 regex to do this.

Here is what I have for the python script:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import shutil

#Sets the buildpath variable to equal replace one "\" with two "\\" for python code to input/output correctly
buildpath = sys.argv[1]
buildpath = buildpath.replace('\\', '\\\\')

#Opens a tmp file with read/write/append permissions
tf = open('tmp', 'a+')

#Opens the selenium script for scheduling job executions
with open('dumplist.txt') as f:
#Sets line as a variable for every line in the selenium script
    for line in f.readlines():
    #Sets build as a variable that will replace the \\build\path string in the line of the selenium script
        build = re.sub (r'\\\\''.*',''+buildpath+'',line)
        #Overwrites the build path string from the handler to the tmp file with all lines included from the selenium script
        tf.write(build)
#Saves both "tmp" file and "selenium.html" file by closing them
tf.close()
f.close()
#Copies what was re-written in the tmp file, and writes it over the selenium script
shutil.copy('tmp', 'dumplist.txt')
#Deletes the tmp file
os.remove('tmp')
#exits the script
exit()
```

Current File Before Replacing the Line:

```
\\server\dir1\dir2\dir3

DUMP3f2b.tmp   
           1 File(s)  1,034,010,207 bytes

\\server\dir1_1\dir2_1\dir3_1

DUMP3354.tmp   
           1 File(s)    939,451,120 bytes

\\server\dir1_2\dir2_2\dir3_2
```

Current file after replacing string:

```
\*.tmp

DUMP3f2b.tmp   
           1 File(s)  1,034,010,207 bytes

\*.tmp

DUMP3354.tmp   
           1 File(s)    939,451,120 bytes

\*.tmp
```

Desired file after replacing string:

```
\\server\dir1\dir2\dir3\*.tmp

DUMP3f2b.tmp   
           1 File(s)  1,034,010,207 bytes

\\server\dir1_1\dir2_1\dir3_1\*.tmp

DUMP3354.tmp   
           1 File(s)    939,451,120 bytes

\\server\dir1_2\dir2_2\dir3_2\*.tmp
```

If anyone could help me in solving this that would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use capturing groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "\\server\dir1\dir2\dir3"
>>> print re.sub(r'(\\.*)', r'\\\1\*.tmp', s)
\\server\dir1\dir2\dir3\*.tmp
```

Then, modify `build = re.sub (r'\\\\''.*',''+buildpath+'',line)` line this way:

```
build = re.sub (r'(\\.*)', r'\\\1%s' % buildpath, line)
```

Also, you shouldn't call `readlines()`, just iterate over `f`:

```
for line in f:
```

Comment: hmmm replacing the build added a third "\" in the beginning of "\\server\", but I was able to replace "\\\server" with "\\server" using notepad++

Thanks for the info.